# Keyboard with Ubuntu Logo for less than $100?

Tags: keyboard, hardware

Is there anyway to get an Ubuntu logo or even a Linux logo for the superkey on a keyboard without spending $100+ (usually $150) on a custom mechanical keyboard? I already have the stickers but my sticker came off. I'd like a more durable solution.

*Edit
I don't own a mechanical keyboard, I own a cheap $20 membrane logitech keyboard from 5 years ago. Regardless, so far spray paint sounds like the cheapest option.

Comment: Ubuntu Store : http://shop.canonical.com/product_info.php?products_id=800

Comment: @Serg Nice keyboard, but... 
1. According to the description, it's "Chinese layout" 
2. It has the Windows logo on the Super key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$6 ["OS" Cherry MX Keycap Set](http://www.wasdkeyboards.com/index.php/products/keycap-mod-packs/os-cherry-mx-keycaps-set-of-2.html) from WASD Keyboard. There are  several different key styles to choose from including Ubuntu Key Style.

Should fit any mechanical keyboard.

Comment: Should do what you want I guess

Comment: The cheapest mechanical keyboard I could find was $80. I guess that's still under $100 total, but still on the high end.

Comment: Are you using a desktop computer or laptop? The normal keyboard you use on a desktop IS a mechanical keyboard (as opposed to laptop style keyboards). You should be able to ping off the key quite easily and replace it (see yputube I am sure for a demo). You're probably looking at gaming keyboards for $80. If you need to buy a keyboard for whatever reason, then you could pick one up for $10-20.

Comment: I'm using a desktop and the keyboard is membrane. I only spent $20 on it. I can easily take the keys off but it's not a mechanical keyboard it's a membrane keyboard. All of those cheap $10-20 keyboards are membrane. They don't have the same base that Cherry MX keys have so they aren't compatible. I can pop the key off but a Cherry MX keycap isn't going to fit in it's place.

Comment: I suppose this is the correct answer however I would to point out that the Turbot Water-resistant Anti-ghosting 87-Key Wired Mechanical Gaming Keyboard With Blue Switch - Black is only $35 on Amazon and it fits the WASD keycaps. So the total price is now down to $41 which is way under $100.

Comment: This answer is not correct at all cherry MX keycaps will not fit the cheep membrane keyboard the OP has, which will lack the correct cherry MX stems. See their edit: "Edit I don't own a mechanical keyboard"

Answer (score 4):

You could always put a sticker on and then something like clear nail polish over it to protect it.

Comment: Good one!  Gets my upvote!  ;-)  (and I would get rid of the comment above as it apparently is an answer to a comment that doesn't exist any more; you want people to vote on your answer, not on your comment!)

Comment: The stickers don't stay on. Although you can sand off the Windows logo and paint on a new one with Acryllic paint if you have that kind of talent or can hire it out. Still, $41 for keycaps and a mechanical keyboard sounds like a better deal.

Comment: This is a cost effective solution which will work on a none mechanical keyboard, IMO this should be the correct answer.